# How to check if a class Exist in java project or not?

Tags: java, exception

According to the requirement I have the name of class and I need to check whether this name of class is exist in a specific package or not. Here is my project structure:

```
app/entities/ <Classes>
app/contracts/CheckClass.java
```

I am writing following code in `CheckClass.java` and getting `classNotFoundException` in file. Here is my following code:

```
public boolean isClass(String className) {
   try {
        Class.forName(className.trim());
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Every-time I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`. I checked the `className` string which is passing correct class name. Is it because of different packages?

Comment: Is this an Android app? A JEE app? A Spring app? An OSGi app? Classloaders vary tremendously across environments.

Comment: @raulk This is play framework app (Java-JEEE) app

Comment: Your className should be a fully-qualified class name. Like java.lang.String. Else, it'll look in the same package.

Comment: @LittleChild I tried it but it's not even loading the same package classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class name has to be full qualified, see [Class#forName(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)):

> For example, the following code fragment returns the runtime `Class` descriptor for the class named `java.lang.Thread`:
>
> `Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")`

In your case: `app.contracts.CheckClass`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)):

> Parameters:
>
> className - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

A fully qualified class name is in the format `package.class`. An example is `java.lang.System`. Always look at the Javadoc.

According to your question, "I need to check whether this name of class is exist in a specific package or not" - I would add an `if` statement to check if `className` begins with the package string.